# Why isn't my full-width horizontal nav bar actually full width?

Tags: html, css, layout

Strange problem this one. I want the nav bar on the following site to stretch the full width of the page.

http://testing.xenongroupadmin.com/bitesize/profile/summary.php

At first glance, it would appear that it is working fine, no problems. However, for some reason there is a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom. When you scroll to the right, the nav bar suddenly stops and just leaves a big empty area.

How can I get rid of the scroll bar so that the page stops at the edge of the nav bar?

The HTML code for the nav bar is:

```
<div id="topbanner">  
<div id="logologin">

<image src="../images/minibitesizelogo.png" id="logo" alt="Xenon Group Bitesize Logo" />

<ul id="topnav">
 <li id="profile"><a href="../profile/summary.php">Home</a></li>
 <li id="choose"><a href="../choose/intro.php">Choose a Course</a></li>
 <li id="about"><a href="../about/whatis.php">About Bitesize</a></li>
 <li id="contact"><a href="../contact/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
 <li id="logout">Log Out</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS is:

```
body  { 
            font-family: arial, tahoma, verdana, sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 62%, #CDEDFA 89%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 62%, #CDEDFA 89%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top , #FFFFFF 62%, #CDEDFA 89%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 62%, #CDEDFA 89%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 62%, #CDEDFA 89%);
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    }

div#topbanner { background-image: url('../images/navbar5.png');
        height: 55px;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
       }

div#logologin { margin: auto;
        width: 950px;
       }

#logo {  
     float: left;
     margin-top: 2px;
     margin-right: 15px;
     margin-left: 23px;
        }

ul#topnav { list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    }

ul#topnav li { 
       width: 153px;
       text-align: center;
       border-left: thin solid #02a2e0;
       height: 39px;
       padding: 0px;
       padding-top: 16px;
       float: left;
       background-image: url('../images/navbar5.png');
       }

ul#topnav li#logout { border-right: thin solid #02a2e0;
          }
```

Any help in resolving this would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wrapper div has a width of 1500px. Remove it or change it to 100% and you should be fine.

Comment: Perhaps one day I'll stop missing the most simple of errors and save myself a lot of time! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Using a Dominspector, I see that your #wrapper got the attribute

```
    width: 1500px;
```

get rid of that and it works fine.

Edit: whoops, too late :V